# awk function is not printing output on the html page

Tags: html, bash

shell scripting code:

```
$head=`echo "$value" | awk '{gsub(/%+/,"\n");print;}'`;
$tail=`echo "$value" | awk '{gsub(/^+/,"\n");print;}'`;
```

html code:

```
$value1="<td><a href=\"$tail\">$head</a></td>";
```

sample input from user:

```
$value= %Link1^www.google.com%Link2^www.facdebook.com
```

output:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Link1</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Link2</a>
```

Comment: please give some sample values of `$value` and the expected output

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: @AasthaArora, kindly post them in your question with CODE TAGS.

Comment: Link1 and Link2 is being saved in $head and google.com and facbook.com is being saved in $tail.and in the html page it should display Link1 link2 and inside link1 and link2 should be google.com and facebook.com basically they should work as hyperlinks

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 okay

Comment: @Kendle sample input: %Link1*www.google.com%Link2*www.facdebook.com

Comment: @AasthaArora, Hello Aastha, thanks for update but sorry it isn't helpful, please do mention clear samples of input and expected output in your question more clearly, we/I can try to help you more, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for replying, okay so let me explain you what's happing the user will enter a value on the input page lets say the user entered  www.facdebook%Link1^www.google.com%Link2^.com this value is being stored in $value then $value is being split into 2 parts using field separator(%,^) and is now being stored into $head and $tail using awk command so now $head=Link1 and $tail=www.google.com and for link2 $head=Link2 and $tail=www.facebook.com,so the output displayed on the html page should be  as shown above in the question

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 can we connect on zoom or meet call if possible pls? I'm new to shell scripting  don't know much about it...and I need to resolve this issue before Monday. pls help

Comment: @AasthaArora, I am trying to understand your question but its not clear, if you can make it clear. Mention it like samples of input(text form, then mention what variables and all you are using) and then mention expected output(not in links in samples only) then I can try to help here more, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sample input from user example= link*google.com
 1)link and google.com is being separated by * symbol.
2)and then the are being saved in $head and $tail
3)so now $head=link and $tail=google.com
4)simple output without link should be link i.e$head on the html page

Comment: Was I able to make my doubt now?@RavinderSingh13

Comment: @AasthaArora, after I applied CODE TAGS to your samples, its a bit clear, let me write it and get back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Also while creating shell variable we need not to use `$` make it without `$` and while printing it only use it.

```
##Shell variable named value.
value="%Link1^www.google.com%Link2^www.facdebook.com"
```

Then following is the code need to be used for generating html code:

```
echo "$value" | 
awk -F'[\\^%]' '
{
  print "<a href=\"https://" $3"/\">" $2"</a>" ORS "<a href=\"https://" $5"/\">" $4"</a>"
}
'
```

---

---

***Generic solution:*** In order to handle multiple inputs from variable, try following `awk` code.

```
echo "$value" | awk -F'[\\^%]' '
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){
    print "<a href=\"https://" $(i+1)"/\">" $i "</a>"
  }
}
'
```

Comment: But I have a query what if the user enters 4 inputs instead of 2 it can be as many as the user wants

Comment: sample input:value="%Link1^www.google.com%Link2^www.facdebook.com%Link3^www.somelink.com"

Comment: @AasthaArora, I have added a Generic solution in my post now, kindly do check once and let me know how it goes cheers.